# Unblocking a subscriber that has never received an email

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a user that subscribed to emails that we send from ExactTarget/Marketing Cloud and emails bounced from day one (full mailbox) and they are now blocked. The only way I can find to unblock them seems to be to get them to click on a link in an old email but they've never actually received an email! Is there some other way to unblock them that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference I worked out how to do this via the SOAP API. The following message will unblock the subscriber. Substitute in the relevant authentication fields and subscriber key.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="***USERNAME_TOKEN***">
            <wsse:Username>***USERNAME***</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">***PASSWORD***</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">***NONCE***</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2016-01-15T05:16:04.200Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:UpdateRequest>
         <ns1:Options />
         <ns1:Objects xsi:type="ns1:Subscriber">
            <ns1:Status>Active</ns1:Status>
            <ns1:SubscriberKey>***SUBSCRIBER_KEY***</ns1:SubscriberKey>
         </ns1:Objects>
      </ns1:UpdateRequest>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```